# How to write ajax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am doing a web, and now I am working on HTML's Form.
I want that my Form has javascript and php, and I need that the javascript has ajax.

When I text my code in my server (it is a server that has PHP) Ajax always responde to me the parameter that i have in the error:function. I don't understand the problem. I watched in diferents web and diferents examples but I can't find a solution.

All scripts are independets and all has their direction right.

Thank you!

This is the HTML (contacto.html):

```
<form id="contacto" method="post" onsubmit="return validarFormulario()" >
    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre (*)"/>
    <input id="correo1" name="correo1" type="email" placeholder="Correo  (*)"/>
    <input id="correo2" name="correo2" type="email" placeholder="Repite el correo  (*)"/>
    <input id="asunto" name="asunto" type="text" placeholder="Asunto  (*)"/>
    <textArea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje  (*)"></textArea>
    <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

This is the javascript (functionContacto.js):

```
var nombre;
var correo1;
var correo2;
var asunto;
var mensaje;
var alerta = document.getElementById("alert");

function validarFormulario(){
    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    correo1 = document.getElementById("correo1");
    correo2 = document.getElementById("correo2");
    asunto = document.getElementById("asunto");
    mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");


    if(nombre.value == "" || correo1.value == "" || asunto.value=="" || mensaje.value == ""){
        alerta.style.padding="10px";
        alerta.style.color="#a94442";
        alerta.style.background="#f2dede";
        alerta.innerHTML = "Rellena los campos marcados";

        return false;

    }else{
        if(correo1.value == correo2.value){

            Enviar();

        }else{
            alerta.style.padding="10px";
            alerta.style.color="#a94442";
            alerta.style.background="#f2dede";
            alerta.innerHTML = "Los correos no coinciden";

            return false;

        }       

    }

}

function Enviar(){  

    nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    correo1 = document.getElementById("correo1");
    asunto = document.getElementById("asunto");
    mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");

    var dataString = "name=" + nombre + "&mail=" + correo1 + "&subjet=" + asunto + "text=" + mensaje;



    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/formulario.php",
        data: dataString,
        success : function(){
            alert('funciona');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
      }     

    });
}
```

And this is the PHP (formulario.php):

```
<?php

    $nombre = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $asunto = $_GET["subjet"];
    $mensaje = $_GET["text"];

    $correo = "Nombre: ".$nombre."\n\nEmail: ".$email."\n\nMensaje:\n".$mensaje;
    $to = "myMail@gmail.com";
    $subject = $asunto;

    mail($to, $subject, $correo);

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting. Have you checked the console output to see if it's telling you something is wrong? Please explain the problem a little better.

Comment: check the developer tools networks tab - inspect the request post parameters - I think you'll find you're doing it wrong ... e.g. `nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");` results in `nombre` being an **element** not the **value** you are looking for

Comment: why
  $asunto = $_GET["subjet"];
    $mensaje = $_GET["text"];
these are post parameters shouldn't they be:
  $asunto = $_POST["subjet"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["text"];

Comment: The console does not show me any errors. When I complete the form and I send it, ajax returns this message that I have in an alert " alert('error');" which is alfinal of the ajax function "error: function(){ alert('error');}"

Comment: And I have $asunto = $_GET["subjet"]; $mensaje = $_GET["text"]; because when I started to do the code I did all with get, but later I deactivated the variables that has get and I  changed the first two by post. When I wrote my question, I forget to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

First, you need to encode the data string properly, in case it contains characters that have special meaning. The best way to do this is to use an object, then jQuery will automatically encode it properly. Also, you need to use `.value` to access the values of the input fields (like you did in `validarFormulario`).

```
var dataString = {
    name: nombre.value,
    mail: correo1.value,
    subjet: asunto.value,
    text: mensaje.value
};
```

Second, in your PHP you need to get all the parameters from `$_POST`, not `$_GET`.

```
$nombre = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$asunto = $_POST["subjet"];
$mensaje = $_POST["text"];
```

Comment: First, thank you for responding. I changed what you told me but now the server needs more timing to run the ajax and now it shows me a bug in the console:
this is the bug:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gWrEcCuDkOaWl4Y1dLak5walE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You were missing `.value` in `Enviar`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I changed tahtyou told me, but I still have the same problem as at firts. When the ajax is executed there are two solutions, `success` and `error`, and the page answers me the second option, the error, and it shows me the alert that I typed in `error: function()`
I understand that I have some failure in ajax because it always gives me the error response

Comment: Go to the Network tab of Dev Tools to see what error is being reported by the AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gWrEcCuDkOaWl4Y1dLak5walE/view?usp=sharing